# Unreal Engine 5 source stimulus

Tags: unreal-engine5

I am trying to have an enemy react to a torch by sight. I added a source stimulus to the torch so that the AI sight of the enemy controller would be able to spot the torch.

The only problem is that the enemy isn't perceiving the torch and I don't know why.
This is the component added to the torch to make it detectable.

```
    stimulus = CreateDefaultSubobject<UAIPerceptionStimuliSourceComponent>("Stimulus Source");
    stimulus->RegisterForSense(TSubclassOf<UAISense_Sight>());
    stimulus->RegisterWithPerceptionSystem();
```

I know the sight is working fine because I can detect the player, the only thing that I can't spot is the torch.